# How to get localStorage working in vue testing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mocha.js, tdd, vue-test-utils

I am trying to test vue components.

I have a vue single file component which uses `vuex`. My states are stored in `store.js` which makes use of `localStorage`. However, when I run `npm test` I get error that reads:

> WEBPACK  Compiled successfully in 9416ms
>
> MOCHA  Testing...
>
> RUNTIME EXCEPTION  Exception occurred while loading your tests
>
> ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

Tools I am using for testing:
**@vue/test-utils, expect, jsdom, jsdom-global, mocha, mocha-webpack**

---

How I run the tests:

```
"test": "mocha-webpack --webpack-config node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js --require tests/JavaScript/setup.js tests/JavaScript/**/*.spec.js"
```

A sample test, `order.spec.js`:

```
require('../../resources/assets/js/store/store');
require('../../resources/assets/js/app');
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Order from '../../resources/assets/js/views/order/List.vue';
import expect from 'expect';

describe('Order', ()=>{
    it('has alert hidden by default', () => {
        let wrapper = mount(Order);
        expect(wrapper.vm.alert).toBe(false);
    })
})
```

In `setup.js` file I am loading jsdom like this:

```
require('jsdom-global')();
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

jsdom-global is using an old version of jsdom. jsdom has supported `localStorage` since 11.12.0.

To use jsdom 11.12+ with `localStorage` support, you can add jsdom `window` properties to the `global` scope yourself in a test setup file that runs before your tests:

```js
/* setup.js */

const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

const jsdom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
const { window } = jsdom;

function copyProps(src, target) {
  Object.defineProperties(target, {
    ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(src),
    ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(target),
  });
}

global.window = window;
global.document = window.document;
global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js',
};
global.requestAnimationFrame = function (callback) {
  return setTimeout(callback, 0);
};
global.cancelAnimationFrame = function (id) {
  clearTimeout(id);
};
copyProps(window, global);
```